# How to insert TimeStamp with Zone Time in Insert Statement

Tags: java, jdbc, timezone

How to insert TimeStamp with Zone Time in Insert Statement...
 Am getting this as String `2011-03-22T13:33:54+0530` 
using following to convert it to time and insert

```
String timStp = 2011-03-22T13:33:54+0530
java.sql.Timestamp tsmp = new java.sql.Timestamp(sdf.parse(timStp).getTime()); 
java.sql.Timestamp tsmp11 = new java.sql.Timestamp(sdf.parse(timStp).getTimezoneOffset());

INSERT INTO PUNCHOUT_USER_LOGIN(REQ_TIME) VALUES(TIMESTAMP '"+tsmp+"');
```

Above query inserted :-->  `22-MAR-11 01.12.44.000000000 PM` (With out Time Zone )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not convert `Timestamp` to `String`. Insert it as `Timestamp`. You can use [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) for this.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO PUNCHOUT_USER_LOGIN(REQ_TIME) VALUES(?)";
// ...

try {
    // ...
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
    // ...
} finally {
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Using prepared statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)